# RADStudio NDK invalid path

Tags: delphi, android-ndk

I'm trying to add a new **SDK for Android** (from the sdk manager of RADstudio under tools), basicly my paths for the jdk and for the sdk are accepted but the one for the ndk (MY_SDK_PATH/ndk-bundle) is not.

What should I do?

- I've already used androidstudio and flagged the ndk checkbox inside AVDmanager
- I've already downloaded and installed the ndk manually

Should I change the environment variables or something else?

Note: I'm using Tokyo 10.2
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem.

I was not able to use the auto installer (the one that RADstudio prompts after the comping error) because the IDE could not find the JDK.

So I tried to set the JDK path manually (changing PATH in environment variables with the correct location), but after restarting the IDE, the problem was still there.

Later, I tried to manually add a new SDK but in the "add new" form the NDK path was rejected (I don't understand why).

At the end, in Tools > Manage Platform > Others, I checked the JDK and the NDK checkbox, problem solved